# Why could not I send no data to New Relic by Python?

Tags: python, newrelic

I want to send data to New Relic.

But I could not send not data to New Relic.
Why?

### Codes

- `pyproject.toml`

  ```ini
  [tool.poetry]
  name = "103"
  version = "0.1.0"
  description = ""
  readme = "README.md"

  [tool.poetry.dependencies]
  python = "^3.9"
  newrelic = "^8.8.1"


  [build-system]
  requires = ["poetry-core"]
  build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
  ```
- `001.py`

  ```py
  from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, DEBUG
  from newrelic.agent import NewRelicContextFormatter


  handler = StreamHandler()
  handler.setFormatter(NewRelicContextFormatter())

  logger = getLogger("test")
  logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
  logger.addHandler(handler)

  logger.warning("test 01", extra={"additional_data": {"test": "test 01"}})
  logger.warning("test 02", extra={"additional_data": {"test": "test 02"}})
  logger.warning("test 03", extra={"additional_data": {"test": "test 03"}})
  logger.warning("test 04", extra={"additional_data": {"test": "test 04"}})
  ```
- `001.sh`

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=xxxxyyyyzzzz \
  NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME=test_app_002 \
  poetry run newrelic-admin run-program python 001.py
  ```

### Tries

1. try 01

   ```bash
   $ ./001.sh
   ```
2. try 02 (using fish shell)

   ```
   $ set -x NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY xxxxyyyyzzzz
   $ set -x NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME test_app_002
   $ poetry run newrelic-admin run-program python 001.py
   ```
3. try 03 (using fish shell)

   ```
   $ set -x NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY xxxxyyyyzzzz
   $ set -x NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME test_app_002
   $ poetry shell
   $ newrelic-admin run-program python 001.py
   ```
4. try 04 (using fish shell)

   ```
   $ set -x NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY xxxxyyyyzzzz
   $ set -x NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME test_app_002
   $ python -m venv .venv
   $ source .venv/bin/activate.fish
   $ pip install newrelic
   $ newrelic-admin run-program python 001.py
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your post, there's a lot of unknowns here. I suggest installing the python agent properly. It looks like you've done it manually.  When you install the python agent properly into the New Relic platform, you'll have access to view UI pages and have better insights to view from.